# Get max value index for a list of dicts

Tags: python, list, dictionary, max

I'm trying to get the index of the dictionary with the max `'size'` in a list of dictionaries like the following:

```
ld = [{'prop': 'foo', 'size': 100}, {'prop': 'boo', 'size': 200}]
```

with the following code I can take the maximum size:

```
items = [x['size'] for x in ld]
print(max(items))
```

How can I take its index now? Is there an easy way?

**Test:**

I just figured I can do this:

```
items = [x['size'] for x in ld]
max_val = max(items)
print(items.index(max_val))
```

is this correct?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Tell `max()` how to calculate the maximum for a sequence of indices:

```
max(range(len(ld)), key=lambda index: ld[index]['size'])
```

This'll return the index for which the `size` key is the highest:

```
>>> ld = [{'prop': 'foo', 'size': 100}, {'prop': 'boo', 'size': 200}]
>>> max(range(len(ld)), key=lambda index: ld[index]['size'])
1
>>> ld[1]
{'size': 200, 'prop': 'boo'}
```

If you wanted that dictionary all along, then you could just use:

```
max(ld, key=lambda d: d['size'])
```

and to get both the index *and* the dictionary, you could use `enumerate()` here:

```
max(enumerate(ld), key=lambda item: item[1]['size'])
```

Some more demoing:

```
>>> max(ld, key=lambda d: d['size'])
{'size': 200, 'prop': 'boo'}
>>> max(enumerate(ld), key=lambda item: item[1]['size'])
(1, {'size': 200, 'prop': 'boo'})
```

The `key` function is passed each element in the input sequence in turn, and `max()` will pick the element where the return value of that `key` function is highest.

Using a separate list to extract all the `size` values then mapping that back to your original list is not very efficient (you now need to iterate over the list twice). `list.index()` cannot work as it has to match the whole dictionary, not just one value in it.

Comment: Brilliant. Just what I was looking for: 'max(range(len(ld)), key=lambda index: ld[index]['size'])'.  I just need to figure out how it woks now :) I'm still at the beginning of my learning experience.

Comment: If you want the dictionary "max(ld, key=lambda d: d['size'])" how would we make sure that "size" exists in d?

Comment: @Kulu if a key doesn’t exist yiu could use `d.get("size", float("-inf"))`; this uses negative infinity as a default value to guarantee those entries are treated as having less than any minimal value. Or, just filter those entries out first.

Answer (score 5):

You can pass the `enumerate(ld)` to `max` function with a proper key :

```
>>> max(enumerate(ld),key=lambda arg:arg[1]['size'])[0]
1
```

If you just want the dictionary with max `size` value, as a Pythonic approach you could use `operator.itemgetter` function as the key:

```
In [10]: from operator import itemgetter 

In [11]: ld = [{'prop': 'foo', 'size': 100}, {'prop': 'boo', 'size': 200}]

In [12]: fn = itemgetter('size')

In [13]: max(ld, key=fn)
Out[13]: {'prop': 'boo', 'size': 200}
```

Comment: Getting `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` with python 3.7.  Can only seem to get `max(enumerate(ld), key=lambda k : k[1]['size'])[0]` to work  using lambda