# Get max value index for a list of dicts where two dicts have equal values

Tags: python, list, dictionary

From a list of dictionaries I am trying to return the dictionary or dictionaries with the highest value. This question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30546889/python-list-of-dicts-get-max-value-index) question but slightly different.

Given a list of dictionaries:

```
ld = [{'prop': 'foo', 'size': 100}, {'prop': 'boo', 'size': 200}, {'prop': 'loo', 'size': 200}]
```

I would like to return the two dictionaries with the highest score i.e. `boo` and `loo`.

If I run the code shown in the question mentioned above:

```
max(ld, key=lambda d: d['size'])
```

I only get the first highest dictionary returned.

Thanks in advance and let me know if you need any clarity.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid there is no simple one-liner for this in `O(n)` complexity. If the performance is not an issue for you, I propose using sort:

```
ld = [{'prop': 'foo', 'size': 100}, {'prop': 'boo', 'size': 300}, {'prop': 'loo', 'size': 700}, {'prop': 'loo', 'size': 200}]

print(sorted(range(len(ld)), key=lambda index: ld[index]['size'])[-2:])
indices = sorted(range(len(ld)), key=lambda index: ld[index]['size'])[-2:]
for index in indices:
    print(index)
    print(ld[index])
```

The results:

```
[1, 2]                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
{'size': 300, 'prop': 'boo'}                                                                                                                                                                                                      
2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
{'size': 700, 'prop': 'loo'}
```

If you need linear complexity, I think you have to write your own code, please consult [Get the second largest number in a list in linear time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16225677/get-the-second-largest-number-in-a-list-in-linear-time)

Please note the answer is in Python 3.

If flexibility in your `O(n)` solution is needed (i.e. which element of dictionary decides about order), you can use something like that:

```
def myfun(mylist, getter):
    for item in mylist:
        print(getter(item))

myfun(ld, lambda item: item['size'])
```

So in this simple example we use a function (created by lambda) `getter` to choose an element from a dictionary. In your code, it will be used to get a second and first maximum element.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I may have phrased the question ambiguously but I'm looking to return the two (or more) dictionaries where the **size** contained within each dictionary is **equal**. I'm also working in python 2.7. Cheers.