# MAX or latest Value from a list of dict in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionary as below

```
[
    {'ClientId': 70433, 'ReportDate': '2020-05-01', 'JobId': 389512, 'AccountPnlCount': 507, 'DeskPnlCount': 545, 'ThresholdName': 'Threshold2', 'RuleName': 'PnlRowCountCheck', 'StartTime': datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 1, 21, 8, 32, 940000), 'CSTTimeStr': '2020-05-01T21:08:32.940000Z'},
    {'ClientId': 70433, 'ReportDate': '2020-05-01',  'JobId': 389525, 'AccountPnlCount': 507, 'DeskPnlCount': 545, 'ThresholdName': 'Threshold2', 'RuleName': 'PnlRowCountCheck', 'StartTime': datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 2, 0, 15, 21, 820000), 'CSTTimeStr': '2020-05-02T00:15:21.820000Z'}
]
```

I need the latest record JobId number Based on StartTime.
i.e. for the MAX of "StartTime" I need the corresponding JobId, which is 389525.

Can you please assist? thank You

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get max value index for a list of dicts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30546889/get-max-value-index-for-a-list-of-dicts)

Comment: Worked like expected. Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `max` with a `key` argument to find the dictionary, then just get the `JobId` out of that dictionary:

```
>>> derp
[{'ClientId': 70433, 'ReportDate': '2020-05-01', 'JobId': 389512, 'AccountPnlCount': 507, 'DeskPnlCount': 545, 'ThresholdName': 'Threshold2', 'RuleName': 'PnlRowCountCheck', 'StartTime': datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 1, 21, 8, 32, 940000), 'CSTTimeStr': '2020-05-01T21:08:32.940000Z'}, {'ClientId': 70433, 'ReportDate': '2020-05-01', 'JobId': 389525, 'AccountPnlCount': 507, 'DeskPnlCount': 545, 'ThresholdName': 'Threshold2', 'RuleName': 'PnlRowCountCheck', 'StartTime': datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 2, 0, 15, 21, 820000), 'CSTTimeStr': '2020-05-02T00:15:21.820000Z'}]
>>> max(derp, key=lambda d: d['StartTime'])['JobId']
389525
```